# Custom Control ControlTemplate DataGrid RowDetailsTempalte binds to same custom control

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF CustomControl (say type "ABCControl") which is using a `DataGrid` as its `Control Template`. Inside this templated data grid's `RowDetailsTemplate`, i am showing another Custom Control (same type "ABCControl").

How can i re-size the column width of the parent `DataGrid` upon "column width change" of the inner `DataGrid`?

Thanks

'ABCControl' uses DataGrid as Template in the Themes/Generic.xml

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ABCControl}">
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ABCControl}">
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Rows.Items}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}">  
 <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Border BorderThickness="0"  Padding="0"> 
    <!--Here Details is a "ABCControl" meaning it will display its conent in another datagrid-->
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Details}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
<DataGrid.Columns>
<!-- First Column--> 
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="1*" IsReadOnly="True">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
<ColumnDefinition  Width="Auto" />
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <!--GridSplitter is used to resize the entire datagrid column upon dragging any column-->
   <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PART_CellSplitter"  local:GridSplitterDragBehavior.IsDragSource="True"
 Tag="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}"></GridSplitter>
</Grid></DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
<!-- Second Column--> 
<DataGridTemplateColumn></DataGridTemplateColumn> 
</DataGrid.Columns>`
</DataGrid>
```

How the RowHeader Column i bound to a Conent control where in i am displaying another control of same type "ABCControl". Meanig RowDetail's 'ABCControl' will also display its content in DataGrid. And user uses 'GridSplitter' to resize datagrid column.

- Now there are two DataGrid (one top "ABCControl" and another RowDetails "ABCControl").
- Current requirement is when user re-size outer datagrid column inner datagrid column should be re-sized  and otherway.

Application's MainWindow.xaml will be using like this :

```
    <conLib:ABCControl Width="400">
            <conLib:ABCControl.Rows> 
                <ItemsControl>
                    <ItemsControl.Items>
                        <!--Row = 1 -->
                        <conLib:ABCControlItem >
                            <conLib:ABCControlItem.ItemContent> 
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </StackPanel> 
                            </conLib:ABCControlItem.ItemContent>
                            <conLib:ABCControlItem.ItemDetails>
                                <local:NewUserControl>
                                <!--NewUserControl uses a the same 'ABCControl instance inside it'-->
                                </local:NewUserControl>
                            </conLib:ABCControlItem.ItemDetails>
                        </conLib:ABCControlItem>
        </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
</conLib:ABCControl.Rows> 
</<conLib:ABCControl>
```

Comment: I think the question is not very clare. You should put some code examples, and make the idea to be clear.

Comment: I fixed it using VisualTreeHelper GetParent and GetChild inside the attached behavior when we start dragging GridSplitter. Thanks